# Closest raster VALUE to a given x,y point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2

Is there a way in ArcGIS to find the closest VALUE in a raster to a given x,y point? There might only be NoData at a certain point, in which case I want to find the closest pixel value.  I can't seem to find a function or combination of functions to do that.

Comment: Are you looking to extract the pixel value at a certain point?

Comment: There might only be NoData at a certain point, in which case I want to find the closest pixel value.

Comment: Have you looked at "Extract Multi Values to Points (Spatial Analyst)" using the bilinear interpolation?  An alternative is to convert the NoData values prior to extracting pixel values.

Comment: thanks! this comes quite close. however, it does not fix the NoData issue. I get <Null> results at places where there is a point but NoData in raster

Comment: Would you prefer a constant such as 0 rather than NoData?  If so, you can convert NoData values using the Con tool.

Comment: I want the exact value of the closest raster cell, which is why can't use Con